# Attach an image inline in an email sent using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, mime

I'm trying to send multiple emails from Excel.

The line `Set attPr = attachment.PropertyAccessor` gives the error

> "Object does not support property or method".

I tried declaring the attachment in as an explicit attachment object (which you can see is commented out). I get the error

> "User defined type not defined"

What I'm trying to achieve, as you can see from my html body (htmlTemp) constructed, is to add the image as part of the email body.

```
Sub Send_Email_Using_VBA_InlineBMPs()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, Email_Cc, Email_Body, Email_Attach As String
Dim htmlTemp, body1, body2 As String
Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single, attachment, attPr As Variant
'Dim attachment As Outlook.Attachments
'Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor

For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
    If sh.Name Like "Sheet 13*" Then
        Email_Subject = "HTML TEST - " & sh.Range("C129").Value
        Email_Send_From = "email@email.com"
        Email_Send_To = "email@email.com"
        Email_Cc = "email@email.com" '; 
        'Email_Body = sh.Range("C124").Value
        Email_Attach = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sh.Range("R3").Value & ".pdf"
        Email_Picture = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sh.Range("R3").Value & ".bmp"

        On Error GoTo debugs

        body1 = sh.Range("C124").Value
        body2 = Replace(body1, Chr(10), "<br>") 'to add newline
        Email_Body = body2

        'htmlTemp = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>"
        'htmlTemp = "<div id=email_body style='font-size: 12px; font-style: Arial'>"

        htmlTemp = "<div id=email_body>"
        htmlTemp = htmlTemp & Email_Body
        htmlTemp = htmlTemp & "<br><img src='cid:" & sh.Range("R3").Value & "' style='max-width: 100%; height: auto;'><br>"
        htmlTemp = htmlTemp & "</div>"

        'htmlTemp = htmlTemp & "</body></html>"

        Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

        Set attachment = Mail_Single.Attachments '.Add(Email_Picture)
        attachment.Add Email_Picture
        Set attPr = attachment.PropertyAccessor
        'attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", sh.Range("R3").Value

        With Mail_Single
            .Subject = Email_Subject
            .To = Email_Send_To
            .CC = Email_Cc
            '.body = htmlTemp
            .HTMLBody = htmlTemp
            '.Attachments.Add (Email_Attach)
            '.Attachments.Add Email_Picture, olByValue, 0
            .send
        End With

debugs:
        If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Note: the picture already exists in a folder.

Here's links to the solutions that brought me to this point. [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388672/vba-to-create-outlook-message-of-content-type-multipart-related) [link 2](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/embed-images-messages-macro/)

Comment: Is this what you are trying? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599739/4539709

Answer (score 0):

To add image directly to HTML email body you have to use following HTML code:
 `<img src='image name + extension'>`

You have to do following:

1. Attache your image to email
2. Add this code to your HTMLbody:`<img src='image name + extension'>`
3. You can add some parameters like height or width.
4. Image name can't contains spaces.

Below you can see example.

```
    Sub Sent_email_with_img()

    Dim my_email As MailItem

    Set out_look_app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set my_email = out_look_app.CreateItem(my_item)

    With my_email
       .To = ""
       .CC = ""
       .Subject = ""

       ' here you have to attache img which you would see in email body
       ' attachment will be invisible
       .Attachments.Add Source:="PATH TO IMAGE\IMAGE_NAME.png"
       ' you can edit width and height of img in email body
       ' I changed width to 400 and height to 250
       .HTMLBody = "<p>This is my image</p>" _
                & "<img src='FILE_NAME.png'" _
                & "width=400 height=250>"
       ' display email
       .Display

      End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: I have similar code and when it reaches .display the image works fine and it can be seen on mobile devices. If I have straight.send it dose not work as on mobile device the image is blank not showing at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your attachment variable points to the Attachments (plural) collection, not to an Attachment object (uncomment the .Add part)

Answer (score -1):

According to my research, I found this article [Use VBA to Change the Name of Specific Attachment when the Send Button it Hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211034/use-vba-to-change-the-name-of-specific-attachment-when-the-send-button-it-hit) and noticed the mentioned:

Outlook will raise an exception if you use Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty to set PR_ATTACH_LONG_FILENAME. You can use Extended MAPI to set the property.